# How to get comparison operator from string to where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data in reference table  like <55, >60 (etc) and in source the values will come 40, 70 (etc). So based on reference values I have to check condition.

Example ;

if the value reference table  is <55

my condition in where clause  would be 40<55

if it is >70

my condition in where clause would be

40>60

actaully I am checking multipule condition on different fileds on where where .. this is going to be one of condition with AND.

Can you suggest me the way to handle it .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the values stored in the same way '<55,>60' or are they two rows as :
<55
>60

If yes then it is not normalized.

Comment: <55 and <60 are two record values not one

Comment: Actually I am checking the multipule condition in my where caluse .. this is the one of condition.

Comment: Then add multiple case construct for the respective operators. Did the answer help, please feedback.

Comment: Sorry Lalit.... i think you misunderstand my Question... I am not looking for output like 40<55,
I want to form where clause A.source_attribute<=B.Referne_attribute based on reference value.

Comment: source 
ename,location,sal
 A,X,10 
 A,x,20 
 B,y,30 
  B,x,40 
ref_table Reference
 ename,location,sal, hike 
A,x,'<30',10% 
B,y,'>30'25%'
 For first record of Ref_table my logic sholud be
 Select Sal from source a left join Ref_table B where a.sal<=B.sal For second record of Ref_table my logic sholud be 
Select Sal from source a left join Ref_table B where a.sal>=B.sal

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> column str format A10;
SQL> WITH ref_data
  2       AS (SELECT '<55' VAL
  3           FROM   dual
  4           UNION ALL
  5           SELECT '>60' val
  6           FROM   dual),
  7       source_data
  8       AS (SELECT 40 VAL
  9           FROM   dual
 10           UNION ALL
 11           SELECT 70 VAL
 12           FROM   dual)
 13  SELECT CASE
 14           WHEN B.val < To_number(Regexp_substr(A.val, '[[:digit:]]+')) THEN B.val
 15                                                                             ||'<'
 16                                                                             ||
 17         Regexp_substr(A.val, '[[:digit:]]+')
 18           ELSE B.val
 19                ||'>'
 20                ||Regexp_substr(A.val, '[[:digit:]]+')
 21         END str
 22  FROM   ref_data A,
 23         source_data b;

STR
----------
40<55
70>55
40<60
70>60

SQL>
```